# Configuring Webstorm to work with Nodejs

Tags: webstorm

I have a problem with webstorm. That is, it does not autocomplete all the time, I've managed my scopes well, so that is not the problem.

The thing is, whenever I try to access methods inside a nodejs app, the only completion I get is `exports`. So, I can get `express.exports.static`, but not `express.static`. How do I fix this?

I am using Webstorm 7 EAP.

Comment: please see [WEB-6922](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6922)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the Webstorm 7 release version.